# What is the difference between Hotfolder and Datahub in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, hotfolder

Is Datahub is upgraded version of hotfolder concept?
If yes, How both are related.
Because hot-folder imports the Impex based on polling time, so data-Hub also work's as hot-folder ?

Comment: It clearly shows that you haven't bothered to go through the documentation. A question without due research and effort is never appreciated on StackOverflow. Apart from the documentation, some of the Q/A threads already available on the internet are https://answers.sap.com/questions/12760998/data-hub-or-hot-folder.html and https://answers.sap.com/questions/12760906/what-is-the-difference-between-data-hub-and-hot-fo.html and https://answers.sap.com/questions/12761040/why-we-go-for-datahub-instead-of-hotfolder.html

Answer (score 0):

The hotfolder is a folder, in which added IMPEX files are imported automatically.
The datahub is a full blown own server solution with conversion possibilities and so on.